# How to design a slogan

Tags: fonts, website-design

Which tools and techniques do you use for designing slogans on website? I tried [this](http://cooltext.com/) one but I wasn't satisfied with it. There is little choice of usable designs and it is aliased in firefox (in chrome is was better).

thank you

Comment: Question converted to Community Wiki per [FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) guidelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Adobe Photoshop and Illustrator to make my jpeg or png logo image. Generally you want the logo to have elements similar to those used in the rest of your site. Color, font size and texture should all be considered in the context of your entire site when making a logo and or slogan.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please describe it more in detail or send some link dealing with logos in this software?

Comment: here is one for designing a logo in Illustrator http://dryicons.com/blog/2009/02/28/logo-design-process-tutorial/ And here is one that is specific to photoshop http://www.eyesontutorials.com/articles/3434/1/Making-the-ATI-LOGO-photoshop-tutorial/Page1.html

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the simpler the better.  A complicated logo (what I believe you are trying to say you want) is actually harder for a client to remember.  A simple logo is usually more pleasing and much easier to remember (such as just a typography effect).  Mess around just typing the name of the website in different fonts and sizes.  Try putting a box around the words etc.

It's best not to use online tools for logos because they tend to look cheap and "cheezy".

Comment: +1 Simple logos also scale better which helps with branding since you can reuse it on paper, stickers, business cards, pens and any other merchandise and giveaways you need.

Answer (score 0):

Consider getting your logo (slogan) created for you, as discussed in this [PW question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2936/design-crowdsourcing-or-hire-a-pro).

Answer (score 0):

A great place to start is to search through font websites such as Font Squirrel (http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) and find some unique typefaces.

You can use their "test drive" feature to type your brand into. This will give you a quick preview of some possibilities.

Once you have a few you like download the ones you want and load them into your graphics program for further development.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Corel Photo Paint all my life and it does pretty good for creating those things. I have to agree that those pre-made logos available on the webs look cheesy and unprofessional.